# Can I delete partitions of an SSD drive?

Tags: installation, partitioning, uefi, ssd

I have an SSD which is installed with Windows 8 and UEFI.

My main concern is that GParted might not be able to get rid of the hidden partitions SDA1, 5, 6 and I'll be left with some kind of legacy UEFI problem.

Assuming I can delete them, I just install Kubuntu 13.10 64bit as normal?

Answer (score 2):

Well, UEFI has to do with the BIOS settings as well.

Installing kubuntu will take care of the drive, you may need to configure the bios to disable uefi booting (boot to legacy mode).

Comment: So if I turn off secure boot control and make the OS selection CSM and then wipe the disk it should work, in your opinion? Or wipe it, go back into the bios and do the OS selection etc?
Thank you for the quick response, I love these forums!

Comment: turn off secure boot and install. If you wish you can "wipe" the drive but IMO that is unnecessary.